# Extract part of a PCB to make a new footprint in KiCad

Tags: kicad, footprint

I have an old PCB KiCad file that I want to modify but I don't have the libraries and footprints any more

Can I extract a part of the existing PCB to make a new footprint for one of the components?

Comment: What version of KiCad was the PCB created with?

Comment: not sure but quite recent (2017), I'm using 4.0.7 now and it opens ok.

Comment: Then you should be able to right-click on the footprint and choose "edit in footprint editor".  Then choose "export footprint" once it opens

Comment: That works great! But I ended up using Hemal answer below.

Comment: Excellent!  I'm glad you were able to get what you needed.  And two ways are better than one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can export all the footprints used in your PCB file to a .pretty folder.

Go to File > Archive Footprints > Create Library and Archive footprints.

You will be prompted to give a name to the .pretty folder. That is it, you should find all the footprints in the project folder. You can modify the footprints in the footprint editor and also use them in other projects.

This feature is available in the version you are using 4.0.7

Answer (score 3):

In KiCad 8, you need to go to pcb file and go to File->Export and choose Footprint To Library or Footprint to New Library